# Entity Framework: enable-migrations in package management console does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I created a very simple project in VisualStudio 2019 to create a database with the Entity Framework (Code First). The database is also created and I can add records (see PrintScreen). 
When I now try to execute "enable-migrations" in the package manager console, I always get an error message:

> ```
> enable-migrations : Das Argument kann nicht an den Parameter "Path" gebunden werden, da es NULL ist.
> In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
> + enable-migrations
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Enable-Migrations], ParameterBindingValidationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Enable-Migrations
> ```

I have tried the call of "enable-migrations" in all variants and with all possible parameters - unfortunately always with the same result. I also started Visual Studio 2019 as "Administrator" - this didn't work either.

The program that works so far:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EntityTest
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Kunde kunde = new Kunde { Name = "MyTestName" };
            using (var context = new EntityTestDbContext())
            {
                context.Kunden.Add(kunde);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public class EntityTestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public const string DbConn = "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=EntityTest; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
        public EntityTestDbContext() : base(DbConn)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Kunde> Kunden { get; set; }
    }

    public class Kunde
    {
        [Required, Key]
        public int KuId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[Visual Studio screenshot with all relevant outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4mUF.jpg)

Comment: Please check whether the right project is select in dialog box in PackageManagerConsole

Comment: Yes, that is done - see also the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is described here:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/1290